# Problem matching colors

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color-match

The background color of my website is a light gray. I have a stock image with a white background that I would like to blend with my background. So I picked a small rectangle of the background and pasted it as a new layer in Photoshop. Then I added a Brightness/Contrast adjustment layer to the stock image below. I moved the brightness slider until the small rectangle disappeared, meaning the colors should match, I should think.
But when I add the image to my site there's still a discrepancy; the stock image background is too dark.

What's the best way to adjust the stock image's background so that it matches my site's background?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Copy the **Hex** or **RGB** color value from the web site CSS file.
- Set Photoshop's **Foreground Color to that Hex/RGB value**
- Create a **New Layer** above the stock image
- **Fill the new layer** with the foreground color (`Edit > Fill`)
- Set the **Blend mode** of this filled layer to **Darken**
- If necessary, create a **Layer Mask** on the fill layer and mask (paint) away any areas which got darker and weren't desired.
- **`File > Save for Web...`**

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. It didn't work rightaway though, but that was my mistake and the reason my solution didn't work either: my "gray" had a little bit of blue in it (#e9eaee), and the stock image I started from was in grayscale mode. After converting to RGB it worked fine. +1, thanks a bunch.